# Odoo 8 - Can't get the content of an object using self.env

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to run a function that's in another model from the one I'm positioned at, the function works but it does not get the info from the object I want to access. I'm sure I'm missing something that I am not seeing but my search online have not helped me so far. Below is a portion of the code.

```
@api.multi
def calcular(self):    
    i = self.env['prueba.productos'].calcular_total(self.id)    
    a = 0    
    if a == 0:        
        raise except_orm('Valor de i', i)
return True
```

What calcular_total does is calculate the total of the price of an item. Or that's what I plan it to, right now all it should do is take the price of the item and just add it 5 and it should return that value. But it only returns 5 and whenever I access the integer variable directly and return it through the except_orm just to see what is in it it returns false, which I don't understand why.
If more info is needed I'll provide it as soon as I can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need the source of the other method too to help you.

Comment: You mean the function I'm calling? That'd be this.

@api.multi
 def calcular_total(self, id):
  total = 0
  total = self.precio + 5
  return total

Comment: So, the model `prueba.productos` has `price` as an attribute, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's ok! I already solved this issue. My original intention was to do all the processing on the other model by calling the function from here. But after reading a bit and trying things out I figured out how to call the record I wanted from this by using search and writting a domain that gives me the values I want through a one2many relation between both tables. Doing this I just do the stuff from here once I get the values I want. It's not what I had in mind, but it works either way. I suppose the function didn't return the values I wanted because I wasn't specificing a record either.

Comment: Great! Congratulations!